# PHP: HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH doesn't exist when requesting page with AJAX

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I searched for an answer in many related questions and none of them actually fix my problem, so I have this code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

}else{
    echo("This page can't be accessed.");
}
```

I tried renaming `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` to `HTTP_X_REQUEST_WITH`, because of another questions answer I saw that sometimes the request is sent as HTTP_X_REQUEST_WITH and not `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`.

but none of those worked, which is quite strange since it worked a few days ago...

Comment: What does `print_r($_SERVER)` show?

Comment: use the console's web browser and see what headers are sent. In all browsers this error occurs?

Comment: It shows: http://pastie.org/private/qwuaj5rceadaumskrssnq

Where exactly can i check what headers are sent?

Comment: What you're doing is quite dangerous securitywise. Anybody can send any HTTP headers she may wish to.

Comment: I don't see why its so dangerous for what I'm going to use it for, I'm using it so in things like: login submit they can't enter that page, I'm aware that them just editing 1 or 2 lines in the browsers console can bypass this, but this is mostly for good looks (So the page isn't completely blank)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I do not mean to Headers received by php, I mean the place where you see next to the browser: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network-files/network_click_sidebar.png Go to the tab `Headers`

Answer (score 1):

AJAX requests don't automatically get HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH headers.

jQuery and most other libraries send it, but if you've rolled your own AJAX, you need to roll your own HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH headers.

Comment: I tried attaching HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header in the AJAX request, but it throws and error i don't know why :/

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` has been changed to `X_REQUESTED_WITH` for major modern browsers.
Note that some browsers may still use `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`.

Comment: The real header is indeed `X_REQUESTED_WITH` but it's PHP which renamed it into `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` when mergin with `$_SERVER` variables